# Python 1 printing an input letter-by-letter with sys

Tags: python, input, sys

I am testing the sys module's ability to print a string letter-by-letter on the same line. When I try to print an input this way, it works until it prints "none". I don't yet know enough about sys to find and correct the problem. I tried finding a similar question on this site, but only found answers for coding languages other than Python 1.

This is the code I wrote:

```
###imports the sys and time modules###
import sys
import time
###defines a function to print the argument letter-by-letter on one line###
desclist=[]
def liner(prompt):
  for i in prompt:
    sys.stdout.write(i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)
###prints input prompt through liner function###
x=input(liner("Enter the input here.")
```

The expected result was the following:

```
 Enter the input here.
```

Instead, it printed the following:

```
 Enter the input here.None
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way that works. After liner(prompt) is run, it stays on the same line unless \n is used:

```
 liner("Enter the input here.")
 x=input()
```

However, I was still wondering if there is a one-line solution so I don't need to enter multiple lines of code every time I print a string.